# how to add additional field in json array structure

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

i need to add addition boolean field то make selectable table of brands and models.
Original json struct is:

```
    {
        "brands": [
            {
                "id": "19",
                "name": "Audi",
                "sort": "1",
                "num": 1,
                "models": [
                    {
                        "id": "190",
                        "name": "TTS",
                        "num": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "189",
                        "name": "TT",
                        "num": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "188",
                        "name": "V8",
                        "num": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "187",
                        "name": "SQ5",
                        "num": 4
                    }
                ],
......
```

i need to add isExpended: Bool = false in brands and models structs. So array should look like this:

```
{
        "brands": [
            {
          --->  "isExpanded": false,
                "id": "19",
                "name": "Audi",
                "sort": "1",
                "num": 1,
                "models": [
                    {
                 --->   "isExpanded": false,
                        "id": "190",
                        "name": "TTS",
                        "num": 1
                    },
```

my models:

```
struct auto_data: Decodable {
    var brands: [brands]
    var gearbox: [gearbox]
    var fuel: [fuel]
    var version: String
}

struct brands: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var sort: String
    var num: Int
    var models: [brand_models]
}

struct brand_models: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var num: Int
}
```

to getting json i use:

```
func get_data (order_type: String, localization: String, version: String, completion: @escaping ([brands]?) -> Void) {
    let encodedBodyParams = "order_type=\(order_type)&localization=\(localization)&version=\(version)"
    let url = URL(string: "http://skat.az/forapi/api/get_data.php")
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: encodedBodyParams, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            do {
                let result = response.data
                let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(auto_data.self, from: result!)

                completion(data.brands)
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            print("models ОК!")
        } else {
            print("error response: \(String(describing: response.error))")
            completion(nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to go through all the elements of the array and put them in another, with the correct structure. Is there another way to change the structure of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that struct and class names start with a capital letter and are *CamelCased*. Further name structs in singular form. In terms of language semantics you are creating one `BrandModel`, not one `BrandModels`

If you need to add custom members in the structs conforming to `Decodable` you have to specify the `CodingKeys`

And in most cases it's sufficient to declare the decoded struct members as constants (`let`)

```
struct Brand: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, sort, num, models
    }

    var isExpanded = false
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let sort: String
    let num: Int
    let models: [BrandModel]
}

struct BrandModel: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, num
    }

    var isExpanded = false
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let num: Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and decision. It's work well ))

Comment: @vadian toggle the  `isExpanded` initial value and save it using `UserDefaults`.When I decode the saved data later it returns all `isExpanded` as `false`.How to solve it?

Comment: @Dilan As `isExpanded` is not in the `CodingKeys` it's not going to be saved. A concrete solution depends on the context

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to parse your JSON and then add the expected new field by iterating over each brands. Finally you would have to stringify the object back to a JSON.

```
1. var obj = JSON.parse('{ your json }');      parse object 
2. obj.brands(2)["isExpanded"] = false;        add new propertie
3. JSON.stringify(obj)                         convert back to JSON
```